# What's event bind in the case that event start immediately when GUI program run?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want that event start simultaneously when program run.

I want that this code display "Hello" immediately when program run. 
This code don't run that way.

How do I change event?

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(380, 200))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1)
        self.tc.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.event) #problem caused here
        sizer.Add(self.tc, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)


        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def event(self, event):
        self.tc.WriteText("Hello")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainWindow(None, -1, "test.py")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to display "Hello" right at the start would be to move it into the init method:

```
self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1)
self.tc.WriteText("hello")
```

Apart from that I have to admit that I don't understand exactly what you want to do. A short delay between program execution and the display of your wx window is natural and can't be avoided.

If you want to employ multithreading in your application you should read up on the python threading system. Unfortunately while threading can make your program more elegant it will result in a worse performance in most cases. The python interpreter can only execute one operation at a time. This is called the GIL - global interpreter lock - and even if you have more than one thread in your application the interpreter will merely switch between threads but not run them concurrently